# How to find repeated sequences of events

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to find an efficient algorithm for identifying a reoccurring sequence of characters. Let's say the sequence could be a minimum of 3 characters, yet only returns the maximum length sequence. The dataset could potentially be thousands of characters. Also, I only want to know about the sequence if it's repeated, lets say, 3 times.

As an example:
ASHEKBSHEKCSHEDSHEK

"SHEK" occurs 3 times and would be identified. "SHE" occurs 4 times, but isn't identified since "SHEK" is the maximum length sequence that contains that sequence.

Also, no "seed" sequence is fed to the algorithm, it must find them autonomously.

Thanks in advance,
j

Comment: Not part of my answer, per se, but may I suggest you look at SWIG and getting your inner-loop work compiled into C++? I've worked on NLP / Machine Learning previously and if-i-could-do-it-over I would put the core algorithms in C++ and link them into the JVM on my computation servers / Hadoop cluster. Just a thought, though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Rabin-Karp [Wiki Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_string_search_algorithm)

Answer (score 2):

Try to create suffix array for string.

Online builder: http://allisons.org/ll/AlgDS/Strings/Suffix/

Check the beginning of consecutive lines in suffix array to match

Answer (score 0):

If you consider that there exist \sum(n) / 2 possible starting strings, and you aren't looking for simply *a* match, but the substring with the most matches, I think your algorithm will have a terrible theoretical complexity if it is to be correct and complete.

However, you might get some practical speed using a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). The algorithm would go something like this:

1. For each offset into the string...
   1 For each length sub-string...

   1. Insert it into the trie. Each node in the trie has a data value (an "count" integer) that you increment by when you visit the node.

Once you've built-up the trie to model your data, delete all the sub-trees from the trie with roots below some optimization threshold (3 in your case).

Those remaining paths should be few enough in number for you to efficiently sort-and-pick the ones you want.

I suggest this as a starting point because the Trie is built to manipulate common prefixes and, as a side-effect, will compress your dataset.

A personal choice I would make would be to identify the location of the sub-strings as a separate process after identifying the ones I want. Otherwise you are going to store every substring location, and that will explode your memory. Your computation is already pretty complex.

Hope this makes some sense! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following algorithm, where:

`str` is the string of events

`T(i)` is the [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) for the substring `str(0..i)`.

`T(i+1)` is quickly obtained from `T(i)`, for example using [this algorithm](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ukkonen/SuffixT1withFigs.pdf)

For each character position `i` in the input string `str`, traverse a
path starting at the root of `T(i)`, along edges, labeled with
successive characters from the input, beginning from position `i + 1`.

This path determines a repeating string. If the path is longer than
the previously found paths, record the new max length and the position
`i + 1`.

Update the suffixe tree with `str [i+1]` and repeat for the next position.

Something like this pseudocode:

```
max.len = 0
max.off = -1
T = update_suffix_tree (nil, str [0])
for i = 1 to len (str)
  r = root (T)
  j = i + 1
  while j < len (str) and r.child (str [j]) != nil
    r = r.child (str [j])
    ++j

  if j - i - 1 > max.len
     max.len = j - i - 1
     max.off = i + 1

  T = update_suffix_tree (T, str [i+1])
```

In the `k`th iteration, the inner `while` is executed for at most `n -
k` iterations and the suffix tree construction is `O(k)`, hence the
loop body's complexity is `O(n)` and it's executed `n-1` times,
therefore the whole algorithm complexity is `O(n^2)`.